# Determining when users password has expired Active Directory, Wrong exception being thrown

Tags: c#, authentication, exception, active-directory, dotnetnuke

When a users password is set to "Change on next Login" in AD, the user cannot login because their password is shown as incorrect. I want to be able to determine this on authentication and prompt the user to change their password.

I Understand to do this I need to catch the `DirectoryServicesCOMException` as described in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664482/ldap-validation-fails-when-user-must-change-password-on-next-log-on-any-solut) however that exception is not being thrown instead the exception being thrown is a `Interop.COMException` which is higher up the inheritance [hierarchy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.interopservices.comexception(v=vs.100).aspx).

This does not contain the required information to determine whether the password needs to be changed or is just incorrect.

```
private bool IsAuthenticated(string Path, string UserName, string Password)
{
    try
    {
        DirectoryEntry userEntry = new DirectoryEntry(Path, UserName, Password); //, AuthenticationTypes.Signing)

        var obj = userEntry.NativeObject;
        return true;
    }
    catch (DirectoryServicesCOMException ex)
    {
        if (ex.ExtendedErrorMessage.Contains(" 773,") || ex.ExtendedErrorMessage.Contains("532"))
        {
            EventLogController.Instance.AddLog("Password expired", ex.ExtendedErrorMessage, Globals.GetPortalSettings(), -1, DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.EventLogController.EventLogType.ADMIN_ALERT);
            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies["sync_expiryToken"].Value = "1";
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    catch (COMException ex)
    {
        EventLogController.Instance.AddLog("Password wrong", ex.ToString(), Globals.GetPortalSettings(), -1, DotNetNuke.Services.Log.EventLog.EventLogController.EventLogType.ADMIN_ALERT);
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Exceptions.LogException(ex);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer eventually,

Certain authentication types only throw a `COMException` rather than a `DirectoryServicesCOMException`

Setting the authentication type to `AuthenticationTypes.None`on the ldap solved the issue.